# Problems with tag notes

Tags: bug, tags

On the [physics tags page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags), the tags `mathematical-physics` and `mathematics` are described as "Just because your question involves math!..."  whereas on the actual pages for the tags,
 the descriptions of both begin, "DO NOT USE THIS TAG just because your question involves math!"

I would have to assume that this is an issue with the rendering of the aforementioned capitalized warning. Is there something we can do about this? For reference...

Here are the search results for the tags on the physics tags page linked above:
[image: Tags: Just because your question involves math]

And here are the actual descriptions of the tags on their [respective](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/mathematics/info) [pages](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/mathematical-physics/info):
[image: Tags: DO NOT USE THIS TAG just because your question involves math]

Comment: Oh yes! It's as though the upper case bit of the description is being skipped.

Comment: Yeah, that seems bogus.

Comment: Have you tried editing the tags' excerpts and wikis?

Comment: @KyleKanos Editing to what? They're at the form we want them, they're just not displaying properly.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this seems like a big [bug](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug).

Just to see what would happen, I added some dummy all-caps text to an existing tag,

> [image]

and then it displays correctly in the Ask a Question page,

> [image]

aaaaaand... bizarrely enough, it displayed incorrectly in the main tags page, but not as incorrectly as the two math tags:

> [image]
>
> (note that THIS IS is missing).

I also did a [dummy edit to one of the math tags](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/348331/revisions) to see if the problem would go away, but it didn't.

There's obviously some text parsing code gone haywire somewhere in the stack that's causing this buggy behaviour and which should be fixed.